# 8 bit BMP image not generated when pixel array is to small richeditable text AS3

Tags: arrays, image, actionscript-3, bitmap, bmp

I don't know if my title can express the issue I am facing right now. 
I'll explain it in detail:

I am generating bmp images from RichEditableTexts, I am using the Bitmap class to get the DisplayObject properties that will allow me to manage it as Pixels.

Then I have this function:

```
    /*
     * Create a 8 bit BMP image as bytearray, with 256 color ( grayscale ).
     * 
    */
    private static function encode( bitmapData:BitmapData ):ByteArray {
        // bit depth configuration
        var bytesPerPixel:int = 1;
        var bitDepth:int = 8;

        // image/file properties
        var bmpWidth:int         = bitmapData.width;
        var bmpHeight:int        = bitmapData.height;
        var imageBytes:ByteArray = bitmapData.getPixels( bitmapData.rect );

        /* Image from Preview size */
        var imageSize:int = bmpWidth * bmpHeight * bytesPerPixel;

        /* Image offset */
        var imageDataOffset:int = 0x436;

        /* File size */
        var fileSize:int = imageSize + imageDataOffset;

        // binary BMP data
        var bmpBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bmpBytes.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN; // byte order

        // header information
        bmpBytes.length = fileSize;
        bmpBytes.writeByte(0x42);             // B                   //0
        bmpBytes.writeByte(0x4D);             // M (BMP identifier)  //1
        bmpBytes.writeInt(fileSize);          // file size           //2
        bmpBytes.position = 0x0A;             // offset to image data
        bmpBytes.writeInt( imageDataOffset );                        //10 4 Bytes
        bmpBytes.writeInt(0x28);              // header size         //14 4 Bytes
        bmpBytes.position = 0x12;             // width, height        
        bmpBytes.writeInt( bmpWidth );                             //18 4 Bytes
        bmpBytes.writeInt( bmpHeight );                            //22 4 Bytes
        bmpBytes.writeShort( 1 );             // planes (1)        //26 2 Bytes
        bmpBytes.writeShort( bitDepth );      // color depth       //28 2 Bytes
        bmpBytes.writeInt( 0 );               // compression type  //30 4 Bytes 
        bmpBytes.writeInt( imageSize );       // image data size   //34 4 Bytes 

        bmpBytes.writeInt( 0x2E23 );          // Horizontal resolution //38 4 Bytes
        bmpBytes.writeInt( 0x2E23 );          // Vertical resolution   //42 4 Bytes

        bmpBytes.writeInt( 0x100 );           // Color in the palette

        bmpBytes.position = 0x36;             // start of color table

        /* COLOR TABLE */
        var table:uint = 256 * 4;
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < table; i++) {
            bmpBytes.writeByte( i ); //B
            bmpBytes.writeByte( i ); //G
            bmpBytes.writeByte( i ); //R
            bmpBytes.writeByte( 0 ); //A
            /*
             * Grays are made of equal bytes, for example: #AAAAAA is gray. 
            */
        }

        bmpBytes.position = imageDataOffset; // start of image data... byte 310 // 1078

        // write pixel bytes in upside-down order
        // ( as per BMP format )
        var col:int = bmpWidth;
        var row:int = bmpHeight;
        var rowLength:int = col * bytesPerPixel; // Bytes per column based on Bit depth

        // Writing bytes to new image vars
        var writingOffset:int = 4 - ( bitDepth / 8 );

        try {               
            // make sure we're starting at the
            // beginning of the image data
            imageBytes.position = 0;

            // Tmp ByteArray to extract 32 bits per pixel 
            var tmpBytes:ByteArray;

            // bottom row up
            while (row--) {
                /* hey += "LINE\n"; */

                // from end of file up to imageDataOffset
                tmpBytes = new ByteArray();
                bmpBytes.position = imageDataOffset + ( row * rowLength );

                // read through each column writing
                // those bits to the image in normal
                // left to rightorder
                col = bmpWidth;
                while (col--) {
                    // Extracting the 32 bits corresponding 
                    // to a pixel per getPixels method ( always the same ).
                    imageBytes.readBytes( tmpBytes, 0, 4 );

                    // We just need one BYTE of the 4 that are in this array.
                    tmpBytes.position = 3;

                    // THIS IS THE INDEX ON OUR COLOR TABLE ( GRAYSCALE ). 
                    bmpBytes.writeByte( tmpBytes.readUnsignedByte() );
                }
            }
        } catch(error:Error) {
            // end of file
            Alert.show( error.toString(), "I/O BMP ERROR" );
        }

        // return BMP file
        return bmpBytes;
    }
```

These are to examples of the DisplayObjects I am making images from:

[image: RichEditableTexts]

The first image is being generated good, but the second one no...

[image: Windows Explorer]

If I open the second one with atom, looks like this:

[image]

Why?
Can someone see something I am missing... this is just... ahhh.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do you have to use .bmp? I haven't come across it in the last 10 years or so. Why not .png? There's an encoder for that built in: `PNGEncoder`.

Comment: Is there a way to make a 8bit png? @null I am using bitmap because of the 8 bits, it is a super small image with an enough grayscale information. I am sending those image to a printer over ftp to be printed, if the image is smaller, but can keep it's quality will work for me.

Comment: Is this solved? If not can you provide links to both `.bmp` files (can check the inside bytes to see where the code made the mistake)...

Comment: PS: Does it work if the second bmp has a minimum height of `0.250` (or even `0.300`)?

Comment: @VC.One don't know if it is solved, but it reproduces just fine [code](http://pastebin.com/THspg0Fb) , [result](http://funkyimg.com/i/2jZdU.bmp) - for text "WWW"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was not adding paddings when it was needed...
This is the resulting code.

```
private static function encode( bitmapData:BitmapData ):ByteArray {
        var bytesPerPixel:int = 1;
        var bitDepth:int      = 8;

        // image/file properties
        var bmpWidth:int         = bitmapData.width;
        var bmpHeight:int        = bitmapData.height;
        var imageBytes:ByteArray = bitmapData.getPixels(bitmapData.rect);
        var imageSize:int        = imageBytes.length;

        // Offsets
        var imageDataOffset:int  = 0x436;
        var colorTableOffset:int = 0x36;

        // Pixel array
        var col:int = bmpWidth;
        var row:int = bmpHeight;
        var rowLength:int = col * bytesPerPixel; // 4 bytes per pixel (32 bit)

        // Padding
        var mod:int = ( rowLength % 4 ) != 0 ?  4 - ( rowLength % 4 ):0;
        rowLength += mod;

        // File size
        var fileSize:int = imageSize + imageDataOffset + ( mod * row );

        // binary BMP data
        var bmpBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bmpBytes.endian        = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN; // byte order

        // header information
        bmpBytes.length = fileSize;

        // DIB header ( 40 bytes version )
        bmpBytes.writeByte(0x42);             // B
        bmpBytes.writeByte(0x4D);             // M (BMP identifier)
        bmpBytes.writeInt( fileSize );        // file size
        bmpBytes.position = 0x0A;             // offset to image data
        bmpBytes.writeInt(imageDataOffset);
        bmpBytes.writeInt(0x28);              // header size
        bmpBytes.position = 0x12;             // width, height
        bmpBytes.writeInt(bmpWidth);
        bmpBytes.writeInt(bmpHeight);
        bmpBytes.writeShort(1);               // planes (1)
        bmpBytes.writeShort(bitDepth);        // color depth (32 bit)
        bmpBytes.writeInt(0);                 // compression type
        bmpBytes.writeInt( ( imageSize + ( mod * row ) ) );         // image data size

        bmpBytes.writeInt( 0x2E23 );          // Horizontal resolution 
        bmpBytes.writeInt( 0x2E23 );          // Vertical resolution

        bmpBytes.writeInt( 0x100 );           // Color in the palette 

        bmpBytes.position = colorTableOffset; // start of color table...

        /* COLOR TABLE */
        for (var i:uint = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            bmpBytes.writeByte( i ); //B
            bmpBytes.writeByte( i ); //G
            bmpBytes.writeByte( i ); //R
            bmpBytes.writeByte( 0 ); //A
        }

        /* Pixel array */
        bmpBytes.position = imageDataOffset;  // start of image data...
        var imgBmp:ByteArray;
        try {

            // make sure we're starting at the
            // beginning of the image data
            imageBytes.position = 0;

            // bottom row up
            while (row--) {
                imgBmp = new ByteArray();

                // from end of file up to imageDataOffset
                bmpBytes.position = imageDataOffset + row*rowLength;

                // read through each column writing
                // those bits to the image in normal
                // left to rightorder
                col = bmpWidth;
                while (col--) {

                    imageBytes.readBytes ( imgBmp, 0, 4 );
                    bmpBytes  .writeBytes( imgBmp, 1, 1 );
                }
                bmpBytes.position += mod;   
            }
        }catch(error:Error){
            // end of file
            Alert.show( error.toString(), "EOF" );
        }

        // return BMP file
        return bmpBytes;
    }
```

Per BMP specification, everytime the row quantity of bytes is not a multiple of four, you have to add padding in order to solve that.

[image]

As you can see I made this code simpler, but if you can see at these lines:

```
// Padding
var mod:int = ( rowLength % 4 ) != 0 ?  4 - ( rowLength % 4 ):0;
rowLength += mod;
```

I am adjusting my rowLenght depending on the actual rowLenght.
Then, later I just need to "take in count" the extra bytes when writing:

```
bmpBytes.position += mod;
```

When filling bytes up:

```
/* Pixel array */
bmpBytes.position = imageDataOffset;  // start of image data...
var imgBmp:ByteArray;
try {

    // make sure we're starting at the
    // beginning of the image data
    imageBytes.position = 0;

    // bottom row up
    while (row--) {
        imgBmp = new ByteArray();

        // from end of file up to imageDataOffset
        bmpBytes.position = imageDataOffset + row*rowLength;

        // read through each column writing
        // those bits to the image in normal
        // left to rightorder
        col = bmpWidth;
        while (col--) {

            imageBytes.readBytes ( imgBmp, 0, 4 );
            bmpBytes  .writeBytes( imgBmp, 1, 1 );
        }
        bmpBytes.position += mod;   
    }
}catch(error:Error){
```